# How to Overwrite file on SaveAs without asking VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am creating an exporter to export the data I make from some `Queries` to `csv` files.

My problem is that I am generating many csv, and my program asks me for each of the files to see if I want to overwrite the previous one.

Is there any way to overwrite them without having to ask me all the time?

```
Dim excel As Object
Dim workbook As Object
Dim sheet As Object

excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\Desktop\NECESARY.xlsx")

'I complete all I want to export here

workbook.SaveAs("C:\Users\me\Desktop\" & file & ".csv")
workbook.Close()
```

This works correctly, and exports all my data perfectly, but as told, I need not to be asked if I want to overwrite the file, there are too many files for going one by one accepting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to delete the previous file before saving:

```
Dim excel As Object
Dim workbook As Object
Dim sheet As Object

excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\Desktop\NECESARY.xlsx")

'I complete all I want to export here

Dim fileName As String = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\" & file & ".csv"

System.IO.File.Delete(fileName)     

workbook.SaveAs(fileName)
workbook.Close()
```

Comment: That worked fine, but i have added  `If System.IO.File.Exists(fileName) Then`, to check if the file exists before deleting it. Thank you @Esko. Have a good day

Comment: It does not matter if the file exists or not because the delete-command does nothing if the file does not exist.

Comment: It might be a good idea to wrap in a Try-Catch to handle any potential permissions problems.